# unable to update p:graphicsImage

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My html code is as follows

```
<p:graphicImage id="graphImg" value="#{imageMB.img1}" width="740" height="480" 
                        cache="false" /> 
<p:commandButton type="submit" value="Next" process="@all"
                             action="#{imageMB.nextImg()}"
                             update=":mainFORM:graphImg"/>
```

Note:In the above code i have tried most of the options for Process (@this,@form,...)

In by Bean i basically pass the StreamedContent

```
public void nextImg(){
    img1=new streamed content;
}
```

Note: My images are not stored in the project location/glassfish its stored in /Test folder.

When i click the next button actually the img1 data changes, but the image in p:graphicsImage remains same.
The same works fine if i refresh the whole page (using F5 or javascript).
I really don't know why it doesn't get refreshed from the update command but works when the page is reloaded.
I use Primeface4.0/Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue with updating `p:graphicimage` on PrimeFaces 4.0 public version. Take a look at the offical forum: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34658

Comment: Thanks,I switch back to 3.5